# ctags for ansible project

Tags: yaml, ansible, exuberant-ctags

I am trying to generate tags from my ansible project via [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net). But it is still not picking the right strings. Bellow are params I am working with. What am I missing? After successful run I expect to have *./.tags* file which will contain all of the tasks names. I am using ctags 5.8 from [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

BTW I started here -- http://blog.iany.me/2015/02/ctags-for-ansible/

*Command*: `/usr/local/Cellar/ctags/5.8_1/bin/ctags -f .tags --recurse .`

*./.ctags*

```
--langdef=ansible
--langmap=ansible:.yml.yaml
--regex-ansible=/^[ \t]*-[ \t]*name:[ \t]*([\w\s]+)\n/\1/i
--languages=+ansible
```

*Example tasks file*

```
---
- name: install docker-py
  pip: name=docker-py version=1.7.2
  become: yes

- name: Install tmux
  yum:
    name:   tmux
    state:  present
    update_cache: yes
  become: yes
```

---

I do not insist on *ctags*. My goal is to have symbols for Atom editor which I could use to quickly jump through my Ansible project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverting to the examples on linked page, made it working. I guess I did the unnecessary changes before I installed ctags from Homebrew

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different implementations of the `ctags` command.

Using the `ctags` delivered with GNU Emacs, I had success with the following:

```sh
ctags --language=none --regex='^[ \t]*-[ \t]*name:[ \t]*\(.*?\)[ \t]*$' *.yml roles/*/tasks/*.yml roles/*/handlers/*.yml
```

This works also with [`etags`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags-Tables.html#Tags-Tables).

Answer (score 0):

universal-ctags has built-in (but incomplete) ansible playbook support.

```
[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% cat foo.yml
---
- name: install docker-py
  pip: name=docker-py version=1.7.2
  become: yes

- name: Install tmux
  yum:
    name:   tmux
    state:  present
    update_cache: yes
  become: yes
[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% ./ctags --version                
Universal Ctags 0.0.0(5567535e), Copyright (C) 2015 Universal Ctags Team
Universal Ctags is derived from Exuberant Ctags.
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Jul 26 2017, 04:24:17
  URL: https://ctags.io/
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex, +multibyte, +option-directory, +xpath, +json, +interactive, +sandbox, +yaml, +aspell
[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% ./ctags --fields=+Kl -o - foo.yml
Install tmux    foo.yml /^- name: Install tmux$/;"  play    language:AnsiblePlaybook
install docker-py   foo.yml /^- name: install docker-py$/;" play    language:AnsiblePlaybook
```